# Extract r.squared from multiple models with purrr::map()

Tags: r, purrr, lm

I have the following three linear models:

```
models <- mtcars %>% 
  split(.$cyl) %>% 
  map(~lm(mpg ~ wt, data = .))
```

Now I want to extract `r.squared` from all of the three models with `purrr::map()`.
I've tried the following two ways but they both produce an error (i.e., "Error: Can't convert a `summaryDefault/table` object to function"):

```
models %>% 
  map(summary) %>% 
  map_dbl(~.$r.squared)

models %>% 
  map(summary) %>% 
  map_dbl("r.squared")
```

What's the issue and how can it be solved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
library(tidyverse)

models <- mtcars %>% 
  split(.$cyl) %>% 
  map(~lm(mpg ~ wt, data = .))
```

Manually doing it you can do:

```
summary(models[[1]])$r.squared
```

And then using `map`:

```
#and in map loop map_dfr
map_dfr(models, ~summary(.)$r.squared)
# # A tibble: 1 x 3
#     `4`   `6`   `8`
#   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1 0.509 0.465 0.423
```

Or

```
 map_dfr(models, ~ glance(.x) %>%
                   dplyr::select(r.squared))

# A tibble: 3 x 1
#  r.squared
#      <dbl>
#1     0.509
#2     0.465
#3     0.423
```

Comment: Indeed, this works. However, I'd still like to know why the method I've outlined above doesn't work for me as other people recommend doing it this way (so it must work for them).

Comment: ive just seen your code, it works for me so not sure why it doesnt work for you: (`models %>% 
  map(summary) %>% 
  map_dbl(~.$r.squared)`). try restarting R

Comment: I've restarted R and it does work when I only run this code chunk. It must be an issue within my markdown document. I'll accept your answer, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
by_cyl <- split(mtcars, mtcars$cyl)

by_cyl %>% 
  map(~ lm(mpg ~ wt, data = .x)) %>%
  map(summary) %>%
  map_dbl('r.squared')
```

https://adv-r.hadley.nz/functionals.html

Comment: This gives you the r2 but OP is working with a list of models and wants to extract the r2 from there... can you orientate your answer to that